# как передать значение из списка в image.network()?

Tags: dart

у меня есть такой вот список:

```
List<Map<String, String>> country = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "cuisine":
        "china",
    "img_url":
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/09/11/14/11/fisherman-2739115_960_720.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "cuisine":
        "turkey",
    "img_url":
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/27/05/48/cappadocia-1773468_960_720.jpg"
  }
];
```

как мне передать значение `img_url` из списка в `image.network()` ?

Comment: А почему бы не создать класс `Cuisine`, затем этот json десериализовать в `List<Cuisine> cuisines`? И тогда `cuisines[0].img_url` - извлекает нужное?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем `img_url` по `id`:

```
var url = country
  .where((id) => id['id'] == "1")
  .where((m) => m['img_url'] != null)
  .map((value) => value['img_url'])
  .toString();
```

Получаем все `img_url`:

```
var list = country
  .where((m) => m['img_url'] != null)
  .map((value) => value['img_url'])
  .toList();
```